# how to split a column into two cells without effecting the rows in table

Tags: html

I want to split column into two cells and without effecting below rows.

Sample image:
[image: sample image]

Comment: What are you tried so far? What does your current code look like? Please add more information so other users can help.

Comment: table 8 columns and 7 rows ,i want to change only 1st column into two columns .if change it effecting to the below rows.

Comment: Please add actual code to your question or you're not going to receive any help from other users.

Comment: what is that image supposed to show us? Looks like a standard table. Sounds like a fun exercise had there been enough information provided to work from

Answer (score 0):

ok here is the code,as you described the tble should have 8 columns and 7 rows and the first row should have only two column.

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td colspan='4'>Ujjwal</td>
<td colspan='4'>Ujjwal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
<td>Ujjwal</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

output images- 
[image: output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Adding another `<td/>` to split the column as usual, and use `colspan` to the same column of at the rest of the rows.

For example:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Row 1 Col 1</td><td>Row 1 Col 2</td><td>Row 1 Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2 Col 1</td><td>Row 2 Col 2</td><td>Row 2 Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3 Col 1</td><td>Row 3 Col 2</td><td>Row 3 Col 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

If I want to split **Row 1 Col 1** to **Row 1 Col 1a** and **Row 1 Col 1b**, you use `colspan` as below:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Row 1 Col 1a</td><td>Row 1 Col 1b</td><td>Row 1 Col 2</td><td>Row 1 Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">Row 2 Col 1</td><td>Row 2 Col 2</td><td>Row 2 Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">Row 3 Col 1</td><td>Row 3 Col 2</td><td>Row 3 Col 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Or, a lazy way is to use nested table.

```
<table>
  <tr><td>
    <table><tr><td>Row 1 Col 1a</td><td>Row 1 Col 1b</td></tr></table>
  </td><td>Row 1 Col 2</td><td>Row 1 Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2 Col 1</td><td>Row 2 Col 2</td><td>Row 2 Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3 Col 1</td><td>Row 3 Col 2</td><td>Row 3 Col 3</td></tr>
</table>
```